# Nextflow DSL2: how to combine outputs (channels) from multiple processes into input of another process by part of filename?

Tags: nextflow

I'm trying to combine outputs from two separate processes A and B, where each of them outputs multiple files, into input of process C. All file names have in common a chromosome number(for example "chr1"). The process A outputs files: `/path/chr1_qc.vcf.gz`, `/path/chr2_qc.vcf.gz` and etc (genotype files).

Process B outputs files: `/path/chr1.a.bcf`, `/path/chr1.b.bcf`, `/path/chr1.c.bcf`...`/path/chr2.a.bcf`, `/path/chr2.b.bcf` and etc (region files). And the number of both file-sets could vary each time.

Part of the code:

```
process A {
  module "bcftools/1.16"
  publishDir "${params.out_dir}", mode: 'copy', overwrite: true
  input:
  path vcf
  path tbi

  output:
  path ("${(vcf =~ /chr\d{1,2}/)[0]}_qc.vcf.gz")
 
  script:
  """
  bcftools view -R ${params.sites_list} -Oz -o ${(vcf =~ /chr\d{1,2}/)[0]}_qc.vcf.gz ${vcf} //generates QC-ed genome files
  tabix -f ${(vcf =~ /chr\d{1,2}/)[0]}_qc.vcf.gz //indexing QC-ed genomes
  """
}

process B {
  publishDir "${params.out_dir}", mode: 'copy', overwrite: true
  input:
  path(vcf)

  output:
  tuple path("${(vcf =~ /chr\d{1,2}/)[0]}.*.bed")

  script:
  """
  python split_chr.py ${params.chr_lims} ${vcf} //generates region files
  """
}


process C {
  publishDir "${params.out_dir}", mode: 'copy', overwrite: true
  input:
  tuple path(vcf), path(bed)
  
  output:
  path "${bed.SimpleName}.vcf.gz"

  script:
  """
  bcftools view -R ${bed} -Oz -o ${bed.SimpleName}.vcf.gz ${vcf}
  """
}

workflow {
   A(someprocess.out)
   B(A.out)
   
   C(combined_AB_files)
}
```

Process B output.view() output:

```
[/path/chr1.a.bed, /path/chr1.b.bed]
[/path/chr2.a.bed, /path/chr2.b.bed]
```

How can I get the process C to receive an input as a channel of tuples (A and B outputs combined by chromosome name) like this:

```
[ /path/chr1_qc.vcf.gz, /path/chr1.a.bcf ]
[ /path/chr1_qc.vcf.gz, /path/chr1.b.bcf ]
...
[ /path/chr2_qc.vcf.gz, /path/chr2.a.bcf ]
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is the second form of the [combine](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#combine) operator, which allows you to combine items that share a matching key using the `by` parameter. If one or more of your channels are missing a shared key in the first element, you can just use the [map](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#map) operator to produce such a key. To get the desired output, use the [transpose](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#transpose) operator and specify the index (zero based) of the element to be transposed, again using the `by` parameter. For example:

```
workflow {

    Channel
        .fromPath( './data/*.bed' )
        .map { tuple( it.simpleName, it ) }
        .groupTuple()
        .set { bed_files }

    Channel
        .fromPath( './data/*_qc.vcf.gz' )
        .map { tuple( it.simpleName - ~/_qc$/, it ) }
        .combine( bed_files, by: 0 )
        .transpose( by: 2 )
        .map { chrom, vcf, bed -> tuple( vcf, bed ) }
        .view()
}
```

Results:

```
$ touch ./data/chr{1..3}.{a..c}.bed
$ touch ./data/chr{1..3}_qc.vcf.gz
$ nextflow run main.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.0
Launching `main.nf` [pedantic_woese] DSL2 - revision: 9c5abfca90
[/data/chr1_qc.vcf.gz, /data/chr1.c.bed]
[/data/chr1_qc.vcf.gz, /data/chr1.a.bed]
[/data/chr1_qc.vcf.gz, /data/chr1.b.bed]
[/data/chr2_qc.vcf.gz, /data/chr2.b.bed]
[/data/chr2_qc.vcf.gz, /data/chr2.a.bed]
[/data/chr2_qc.vcf.gz, /data/chr2.c.bed]
[/data/chr3_qc.vcf.gz, /data/chr3.c.bed]
[/data/chr3_qc.vcf.gz, /data/chr3.b.bed]
[/data/chr3_qc.vcf.gz, /data/chr3.a.bed]
```

Note that when two or more [queue](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel) channels are declared as process inputs (like in your `process A`), the process will block until it receives a value from each input channel. As these are run in parallel and asynchronously, there's no guarantee that items will be emitted in the order that they were received. This can result in mix-ups, where for example, you unexpectedly end up with an index file that belongs to another VCF. Most of the time, what you want is one [queue](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel) channel and one or more [value](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel) channels. The section in the docs on [multiple input channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-multiple-input-channels) explains this quite well in my opinion, and is well worth the time reading if you haven't already. Also, joining and combining channels becomes a lot easier when your processes define tuples in their input and output declarations, where the first element is a key, like a sample name/id. I think you want something something like the following:

```
params.vcf_files = './data/*.vcf.gz{,.tbi}'
params.sites_list = './data/sites.tsv'
params.chr_lims = './data/file.txt'

params.outdir = './results'
```

```
process proc_A {

    tag "${sample}: ${indexed_vcf.first()}"

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/proc_A", mode: 'copy', overwrite: true

    module "bcftools/1.16"

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(indexed_vcf)
    path sites_list

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${sample}_qc.vcf.gz{,.tbi}")

    script:
    def vcf = indexed_vcf.first()

    """
    bcftools view \\
        -R "${sites_list}" \\
        -Oz \\
        -o "${sample}_qc.vcf.gz" \\
        "${vcf}"
    bcftools index \\
        -t \\
        "${sample}_qc.vcf.gz"
    """
}
```

```
process proc_B {

    tag "${sample}: ${indexed_vcf.first()}"

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/proc_B", mode: 'copy', overwrite: true

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(indexed_vcf)
    path chr_lims

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("*.bed")

    script:
    def vcf = indexed_vcf.first()

    """
    split_chr.py "${chr_lims}" "${vcf}"
    """
}
```

```
process proc_C {

    tag "${sample}: ${indexed_vcf.first()}: ${bed.name}"

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/proc_C", mode: 'copy', overwrite: true

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(indexed_vcf), path(bed)

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${bed.simpleName}.vcf.gz")

    script:
    def vcf = indexed_vcf.first()

    """
    bcftools view \\
        -R "${bed}" \\
        -Oz \\
        -o "${bed.simpleName}.vcf.gz" \\
        "${vcf}"
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    vcf_files = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.vcf_files )

    sites_list = file( params.sites_list )
    chr_lims = file( params.chr_lims )

    proc_A( vcf_files, sites_list )
    proc_B( proc_A.out, chr_lims )

    proc_A.out \
        | combine( proc_B.out, by: 0 ) \
        | map { sample, indexed_vcf, bed_files ->
            bed_list = bed_files instanceof Path ? [bed_files] : bed_files

            tuple( sample, indexed_vcf, bed_list )
        } \
        | transpose( by: 2 ) \
        | proc_C \
        | view()
}
```

The above should produce results like:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.0
Launching `main.nf` [mighty_elion] DSL2 - revision: 5ea25ae72c
executor >  local (15)
[b4/08df9d] process > proc_A (foo: foo.vcf.gz)           [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[93/55e467] process > proc_B (foo: foo_qc.vcf.gz)        [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[8b/cd7193] process > proc_C (foo: foo_qc.vcf.gz: b.bed) [100%] 9 of 9 ✔
[bar, ./work/90/53b9c6468ca54bb0f4eeb99ca82eda/a.vcf.gz]
[bar, ./work/24/cca839d5f63ee6988ead96dc9fbe1d/b.vcf.gz]
[bar, ./work/6f/61e1587134e68d2e358998f61f6459/c.vcf.gz]
[baz, ./work/f8/1484e94b9187ba6aae81d68f0a18cf/b.vcf.gz]
[baz, ./work/9c/20578262f5a2c13c6c3b566dc7b7d8/c.vcf.gz]
[baz, ./work/f5/3405b54f81f6f500a3ee4a78f5e6df/a.vcf.gz]
[foo, ./work/39/945fb0d3f375260e75afbc9caebc5d/a.vcf.gz]
[foo, ./work/de/cecd94ff39f204e799cb8e4c4ad46f/c.vcf.gz]
[foo, ./work/8b/cd7193107f6be5472d2e29982e3319/b.vcf.gz]
```

Also note that [third party scripts](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/sharing.html#third-party-scripts), like your Python script, can be moved to a folder called `bin` in the root of your project repository (i.e. the same directory as your `main.nf`). And if you make your script executable, you will be able to invoke "as-is", i.e. without the need for an absolute path to it.

Comment: Thank you, Steve, for detailed explanation, now I have better understanding of the topic and pipeline works like a charm.

Comment: I have a question about transpose operator. What to do, if the channel for some chrs has only one set of files. For example: 
`chr20: [chr20.vcf, [chr20.a.bed]]
chr1: [chr1.vcf, [chr1.a.bed, chr1.b.bed,...]]`
The transpose gives and error for chr20, is there any workaround for such cases?

Comment: @Vickie It looks like you have a channel of maps? How was this channel created? The transpose operator needs a channel of tuples to create a transposition.

Comment: it's `proc_A.out | combine( proc_B.out, by: 0 ) | transpose( by: 2 ) | proc_C | view()` And it's working fine except the situation, when proc_B returns only one bed file, usually there are more than one.

Comment: Ah sorry about that @Vickie - I completely forgot that if a process only creates a single file, it will return a Path object even though we anticipate an ArrayList. Please see the changes above.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with channel operators. Check the code below, with some comments:

```
workflow {

  // Let's start by building channels similar to the ones you described
  Channel
    .of(file('/path/chr1_qc.vcf.gz'), file('/path/chr2_qc.vcf.gz'))
    .set { pAoutput}
  Channel
    .of(file('/path/chr1.a.bcf'), file('/path/chr1.b.bcf'), file('/path/chr1.c.bcf'),
        file('/path/chr2.a.bcf'), file('/path/chr2.b.bcf'), file('/path/chr2.c.bcf'))
    .set { pBoutput }

  // Now, let's create keys to relate the elements in the two channels
  pAoutput
    .map { filepath -> [filepath.name.tokenize('_')[0], filepath ] }
    .set { pAoutput_tuple }
  // The channel now looks like this:
  // [chr1, /path/chr1_qc.vcf.gz]
  // [chr2, /path/chr2_qc.vcf.gz]
  pBoutput
    .map { filepath -> [filepath.name.tokenize('.')[0], filepath ] }
    .set { pBoutput_tuple }
  // And:
  // [chr1, /path/chr1.a.bcf]
  // [chr1, /path/chr1.b.bcf]
  // [chr1, /path/chr1.c.bcf]
  // [chr2, /path/chr2.a.bcf]
  // [chr2, /path/chr2.b.bcf]
  // [chr2, /path/chr2.c.bcf]

  // Combine the two channels and group by key
  pAoutput_tuple
    .mix(pBoutput_tuple)
    .groupTuple()
    .flatMap { chrom, path_list ->
      path_list.split {
        it.name.endsWith('.vcf.gz')
      }.combinations()
    }
    .view()
}
```

You can check the output below:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.4
Launching `ex.nf` [maniac_pike] DSL2 - revision: f87873ef13
[/path/chr1_qc.vcf.gz, /path/chr1.a.bcf]
[/path/chr1_qc.vcf.gz, /path/chr1.b.bcf]
[/path/chr1_qc.vcf.gz, /path/chr1.c.bcf]
[/path/chr2_qc.vcf.gz, /path/chr2.a.bcf]
[/path/chr2_qc.vcf.gz, /path/chr2.b.bcf]
[/path/chr2_qc.vcf.gz, /path/chr2.c.bcf]
```

Comment: Mixing the channels only to divide up the items again is tedious in my opinion. Note that you could replace your map and flatMap blocks with: `.flatMap { chrom, path_list -> path_list.split { it.name.endsWith('.vcf.gz') }.combinations() }`. This would ensure that files in the first channel belonging to the same chromosome would be handled correctly.

Comment: Thanks, Steve! Very nice what you did in these closures! I will edit the answer to use it instead.