# Combining output files from different process and used as input in next process

Tags: nextflow

With reference to the previous asked question
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75100652/nextflow-dsl2-how-to-combine-outputs-channels-from-multiple-processes-into-in?rq=1))
I have to combine the outputs from previous two processes and used them as an input to next process

```
process A {
  
  publishDir params.trim, mode : 'copy' 

  input:
  tuple val(pair_id), file(recal_readsbamfile)

  output:
  tuple val(pair_id),file(normal_samplefile), emit : SM_normalbam
  tuple val(pair_id),file(normal_samplefile_bai), emit : SM_normal_bai


  script:
  normal_samplefile = pair_id + '_recal_reads_SM.bam'
  normal_samplefile_bai = pair_id + '_recal_reads_SM.bai'

  """
    
  ./gatk --java-options "-Xmx24G" AddOrReplaceReadGroups --INPUT $recal_readsbamfile --OUTPUT $normal_samplefile --RGLB lib1 --RGPL illumina --RGPU NONE --RGSM NORMAL_$pair_id
  ./gatk --java-options "-Xmx24G" BuildBamIndex --INPUT $normal_samplefile

process B {
  
  publishDir params.trim, mode : 'copy' 

  input:
  tuple val(pair_id), file(recal_readsbamfile)

  output:
  tuple val(pair_id),file(tumor_samplefile), emit : SM_tumorbam
  tuple val(pair_id),file(tumor_samplefile_bai), emit : SM_tumorbam_bai


  script:
  tumor_samplefile = pair_id + '_recal_reads_SM.bam'
  tumor_samplefile_bai = pair_id + '_recal_reads_SM.bai'

  """
    
  ./gatk --java-options "-Xmx24G" AddOrReplaceReadGroups --INPUT $recal_readsbamfile --OUTPUT $tumor_samplefile --RGLB lib1 --RGPL illumina --RGPU NONE --RGSM TUMOR_$pair_id
  ./gatk --java-options "-Xmx24G" BuildBamIndex --INPUT $tumor_samplefile
  
process M {
 
    publishDir params.trim, mode : 'copy'

  input:
  tuple val(pair_id), file(tumor_samplefile),  file(normal_samplefile)

  output:
  tuple val(pair_id),file(flr2_file), emit : flr
  tuple val(pair_id),file(pon_file),  emit : pons

 script:

 flr2_file = pair_id + '_f1r2.tar.gz'
 pon_file =  pair_id + '_somatic_variants_PON.vcf' 

 """
./gatk --java-options "-Xmx24G"  Mutect2 --native-pair-hmm-threads 20 -R ${params.reference} ${tumor_samplefile} ${normal_samplefile --normal-sample ${normalRGSM} -pon ${params.ponsfile} -germline-resource ${params.germlineresource} -L ${params.intervalfile} --f1r2-tar-gz  ${name}.f1r2.tar.gz --output ${name}.mutect2.unfiltered.vcf
```

process A and process B have almost similar named output varies in a way that

1. process A output - patient_1_T_recal_reads.bam
2. process B output -patient_1_N_recal_reads.bam

i have to include both the files together in next process(M) in a way that -I patient_1_T_recal_reads.bam -I patient_1_N_recal_reads.bam  -normal patient_1_N

i have followed the previous asked similar question but got stuck with new channel creation as i have multiple samples so is there any other way to proceed instead of giving path for every file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you want to combine the items emitted from two channels, you're looking for the cartesian product. For this, you would want the [combine](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#combine) operator. However, your first two processes are almost identical and could be refactored into a single definition which could then be included from another workflow script (using the [`include`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#module-inclusion) keyword). Unless you *really* need to prefix your sample names, I would just use them as-is and supply the normal sample when running Mutect2. For example:

```
params.bam_files = './bam_files/*_recal.bam'
params.outdir = './results'

params.reference = './igenomes/Homo_sapiens/GATK/GRCh38/Sequence/WholeGenomeFasta/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta'
params.sequence_dict = './igenomes/Homo_sapiens/GATK/GRCh38/Sequence/WholeGenomeFasta/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.dict'
params.germline_resource = './igenomes/Homo_sapiens/GATK/GRCh38/Annotation/GermlineResource/gnomAD.r2.1.1.GRCh38.PASS.AC.AF.only.vcf.gz'
params.pon ='./igenomes/Homo_sapiens/GATK/GRCh38/Annotation/GATKBundle/1000g_pon.hg38.vcf.gz'
params.intervals = './intervals.bed'
```

```
process AddOrReplaceReadGroups {

    tag { sample }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/AddOrReplaceReadGroups", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(bam)
    val library
    val platform
    val barcode

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${bam.baseName}_SM.bam{,.bai}")

    script:
    def avail_mem = task.memory ? "${task.memory.toGiga()}G" : "1G"
    def java_opts = "-XX:+UseSerialGC -Xmx${avail_mem}"

    """
    gatk --java-options "${java_opts}" AddOrReplaceReadGroups \\
        --INPUT "${bam}" \\
        --OUTPUT "${bam.baseName}_SM.bam" \\
        --RGLB "${library}" \\
        --RGPL "${platform}" \\
        --RGPU "${barcode}" \\
        --RGSM "${sample}"
    gatk --java-options "${java_opts}" BuildBamIndex \\
        --INPUT "${bam.baseName}_SM.bam" \\
        --OUTPUT "${bam.baseName}_SM.bam.bai"
    """
}
```

```
process Mutect2 {

    tag { pair_id }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/Mutect2", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple(
        val(pair_id),
        val(tumor_sample), path(indexed_tumor_bam),
        val(normal_sample), path(indexed_normal_bam),
    )
    path indexed_fasta
    path sequence_dict
    path germline_resource
    path pon
    path intervals

    output:
    tuple val(pair_id), path("${pair_id}.mutect2.vcf{,.idx}"), emit: vcf
    tuple val(pair_id), path("${pair_id}.f1r2.tar.gz"), emit: f1r2

    script:
    def avail_mem = task.memory ? "${task.memory.toGiga()}G" : "1G"
    def java_opts = "-XX:+UseSerialGC -Xmx${avail_mem}"

    """
    gatk --java-options "${java_opts}" Mutect2 \\
        --input "${indexed_tumor_bam.first()}" \\
        --input "${indexed_normal_bam.first()}" \\
        --output "${pair_id}.mutect2.vcf" \\
        --reference "${indexed_fasta.first()}" \\
        --sequence-dictionary "${sequence_dict}" \\
        --native-pair-hmm-threads ${task.cpus} \\
        --normal-sample "${normal_sample}" \\
        --panel-of-normals "${pon.first()}" \\
        --germline-resource "${germline_resource.first()}" \\
        --intervals "${intervals}" \\
        --f1r2-tar-gz "${pair_id}.f1r2.tar.gz"
    """
}
```

As you can see, my preference is to keep the BAM and index files together in the same channel. I also prefer basing my output files off of a file, rather than some string. This approach almost always guarantees a unique output filename so we don't accidentally clobber our inputs. An example workflow might looks like:

```
workflow {

    Channel
        .fromFilePairs( params.bam_files, size: 1, flat: true )
        .tap { bam_files }
        .map { sample, bam ->
            pair_id = sample.substring(0, sample.lastIndexOf('_'))

            tuple( pair_id, sample )
        }
        .set { samples }

    reference = file( "${params.reference}{,.fai}" )
    sequence_dict = file( params.sequence_dict )
    germline_resource = file( "${params.germline_resource}{,.tbi}" )
    pon = file( "${params.pon}{,.tbi}" )
    intervals = file( params.intervals )

    AddOrReplaceReadGroups( bam_files, 'lib1', 'illumina', 'NONE' )

    samples
        .map { pair_id, sample -> tuple( sample, pair_id ) }
        .join( AddOrReplaceReadGroups.out )
        .branch { sample, pair_id, indexed_bam ->

            tumor: sample.endsWith('_T')
                return tuple( pair_id, sample, indexed_bam )

            normal: sample.endsWith('_N')
                return tuple( pair_id, sample, indexed_bam )

            other: true
        }
        .set { samples }

    Mutect2(
        samples.tumor.join( samples.normal ),
        reference,
        sequence_dict,
        germline_resource,
        pon,
        intervals,
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Sir, i will implement the way as suggested by you and will update.